# ERROR: Could not read [class java.lang.String]; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException

Tags: java, resttemplate

I am getting the following exception:
`ERROR [tomcat-http--39] (Controller.java:193) - Could not read [class java.lang.String]; nested exception is org.springframewor
k.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveCl
assException: response : response`

The code itself is pretty simple and this call works in postman.

```
private boolean insertContactInSilverpop(String email, String token) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    final String url = "https://api1.silverpop.com:443/rest/databases/...";
    String requestJson = new StringBuilder("{\"email\":\"")
            .append(email)
            .append("\",\"emailType\":\"HTML\",\"leadSource\":\"internal pop-up\",\"optInDetails\":\"User Name: name, IP Address: 0.0.0.0\"}")
            .toString();

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> result = null;
    try {       
        result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
        return result.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED;                    
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

It successfully inserts the data but throws an exception while doing that.
EDIT: adding api response:

```
{
"meta": {
    "attributes": {},
    "generalErrors": [],
    "fieldErrors": {},
    "links": [],
    "nextPageUrl": null
},
"data": {
    "location": "https://api1.silverpop.com/rest/databases/111/contacts/123",
    "id": 123
}
```

}

Comment: Can you also please paste the response of the API as seen in (working) postman? Also the spring config where you have defined any HTTP message converters or not?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it via old HttpURLConnection method and it worked.
Just in case if someone comes across this here is my solution:

```
private boolean insertContactInSilverpop(String email, String tokenSp) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    final String urlStr = "https://api1.silverpop.com:443/rest/databases/111/contacts";
    String requestJson = new StringBuilder("{\"email\":\"").append(email)
            .append("\",\"emailType\":\"HTML\",\"leadSource\":\"internal pop-up\",\"optInDetails\":\" IP Address: 0.0.0.0\"}").toString();

    byte[] postDataBytes = requestJson.getBytes("UTF-8");
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenSp);
    conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.write(postDataBytes);
    }

    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        sb.append((char) c);
    String response = sb.toString();

    log.info(response);
    int code = conn.getResponseCode();

    return code == 201;

}
```